# Split view to open more than 2 instances in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I know how to open two instances at the same window by using **clone** option in **View**. But can  we open more than two instances in Notepad++?  I tried to **Clone to Other View** from one instance but it just moves to another instance instead of creating new instance.

I want to edit big source file in 3 different parts. So I want to know whether notepad++ can do this.

Comment: Hi did you find an answer to this? I'd also like to open more than 2 files

Comment: I've realized Notepad++ cannot do this and i'm moving to Sublime2 which does open multiple files as needed.

Comment: No I didn't find answer to this. I also moved to Sublime2 which is very effective for given task.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `open in new instance`. And then reopen the new file on the original instance.

or do `open in new instance` 3 times and close the original one.

or `move to new instance` ...

Doesn't matter as long as you have 3 open instances with the same file.

However you have to keep in mind that the changes you make on one instance will not be visible in others unless you save the file.

I recommend using `clone to other view`. Because you can work on both views with the changes synchronized with out having to save the file every time.

If you need to go from one location to other often (i.e. assuming that is the reason) I recommend you use bookmarks. and just press `F2` to iterate through them.

Comment: This answer does not make sense, or I don't get it clearly. The user is trying to open three files, in as much views under one window. So, your answer does not have a solution for that problem

Comment: I'd also like to open more than two files within the same instance. Not loading multiple instances of Notepad++. Move to other view seems to only open two windows max.

Answer (score 2):

You can have only two views....per window. If you set your notepad window to (say) left half of screen (start + left arrow) then drag a tab into the other half it opens a new instance. Set that mew instance to other half, and you can have two views. If you have 3 monitors......12 files, but cloned files will give some problems.